# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" has no influence in REST Web Service

Tags: rest, jquery, cross-domain, jersey

I make an AJAX call from JavaScript client (running on machine A) to Web server (running on machine B).
Client tries to access a URL exposed by RESTful Web service (Jersey), and it is blocked with error:

> Origin http://localhost/ is not
>   allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin

In server I added 2 header parameters that allow access to any client. However it didn't help:

```
@Context
private HttpServletResponse servlerResponse;

@POST
@Path("testme")
public void test(){
    servlerResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    servlerResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}
```

The same headers work in case of JSP:

```
<%
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
%>
<html>
<head><title>test jsp</title></head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

thanks

P.S the client part is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/login/testme",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onLoginSuccess,
    error: onLoginError
});
```

Comment: What does your XmlHttpRequest client code look like?  Is it using POST?  Because your servlet looks like its configured for POST only.

Comment: My client is using POST.

Comment: Found a solution: configure a filter that adds the required headers to every response.

Comment: can you add some more information on how you did that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a solution, we implemented javax.servlet.Filter that adds required headers to every response:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    // This should be added in response to both the preflight and the actual request
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: but i am getting error when i make a call to rest service through ajax.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, I did...Please see this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178823/jqery-call-of-java-rest-service-not-working-cors
Thanks.Kumar Shorav

Answer (score 3):

@epeleg This is my preferred way of doing things like this is to do filtering of response (Jersey 2.x):

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```